# Custom Title bar showing up white-ish in WinUI 3

Tags: xaml, debugging, winui-3

I'm back with another problem in my browser that I'm working on. I made a custom title bar where the Tabs come into the title bar to create a more immersive experience. but all that "Immersive experience" is being ruined by this seemingly unfixable bug. what ive tried to do is change the background of the `CustomDragRegion` Element.
[image: My App]

look at the title bar. its disgusting. someone help me. plss

heres the code:

```
<Window
x:Class="Microsoft_Edge_WebView2_Runtime_Application.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Microsoft_Edge_WebView2_Runtime_Application"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid BorderBrush="Transparent" x:Name="Browser" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentRevealBorderBrush}">
    <TabView Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" x:Name="Tabv" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddTabButtonClick" TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested">
        <TabViewItem FontFamily="Gellix" x:Name="HomeTab" Header="Home" IsClosable="False">
            <TabViewItem.IconSource>
                <SymbolIconSource Symbol="Document" />
            </TabViewItem.IconSource>

            <Grid x:Name="TabContent" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#282828">
                <WebView2 x:Name="WebView" Source="https://google.com" Margin="0,52,0,0"/>
                <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="666">
                    <TextBox KeyDown="AddressBar_KeyDown" FontFamily="Gellix" x:Name="AddressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="576" PlaceholderText="Search or type a URL here..." TextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button Height="32" Width="40" x:Name="Home" Click="Button_Click_1">
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xE80F;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Height="32" Width="40" x:Name="Go" Margin="626,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click">
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xE751;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Button x:Name="Refresh" Margin="0,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="40" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xe72c;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="Backward" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="40" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Click="Backward_Click">
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xf0d3;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="Forward" Margin="53,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="40" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Click="Forward_Click">
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons" Glyph="&#xF0D2;" Margin="-2,-1,-2,-1"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </TabViewItem>
        <TabView.TabStripFooter>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0"  x:Name="CustomDragRegion" Background="Transparent"/>
        </TabView.TabStripFooter>
    </TabView>


</Grid>
```

if you really need c# code then just comment. cuz I have only two lines of c# related to the title bar.

Comment: How do you extend the title?  Via Window, or via AppWindow?

Comment: I use `ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;` and `SetTitleBar(CustomDragRegion)`

Comment: those are the 2 lines in cs for titlebar

Comment: this is WinUI 3 by the way

Comment: Try AppWindow: appWindow.TitleBar.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;

Comment: that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able set the tittle bar to the color defined in the xaml by setting the `WindowCaptionsBackground` and `WindowCaptionsBackgroundDisabled` properties to `Transparent`, as such:

App.xaml

```
<Application
    ...
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other app resources here -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionBackground">Transparent</SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionBackgroundDisabled">Transparent</SolidColorBrush>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
    
</Application>
```

More info on customizing the tittle bar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui3